# JSONPath query - parse object of object

Tags: jsonpath

I'm trying to write a JsonPath query that selects a specific object based on a condition.

I would like to select all volumes with a name containing 'mydrive' and 'hosts' array with no value. Can you help me to get the good JSONPath query?

With this json output

```
{
    "purefa_info": {
            "volumes": {
                "DATASTORE": {
                    "bandwidth": null,
                    "host_encryption_key_status": "none",
                    "hosts": [
                        {
                            "host": "esxi1",
                            "lun": 251
                        },
                        {
                            "host": "esxi2",
                            "lun": 251
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "RC1Clone": {
                    "bandwidth": null,
                    "host_encryption_key_status": "none",
                    "hosts": []
                },
                "RC2Clone": {
                    "bandwidth": null,
                    "host_encryption_key_status": "none",
                    "hosts": []
                },
                "mydrive-0d32e3799a": {
                    "bandwidth": null,
                    "host_encryption_key_status": "none",
                    "hosts": []
                },
                "mydrive-0e35cb6455": {
                    "bandwidth": null,
                    "host_encryption_key_status": "none",
                    "hosts": [
                        {
                            "host": "esxi1",
                            "lun": 251
                        },
                        {
                            "host": "esxi2",
                            "lun": 251
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "mydrive-55c61ab79c": {
                    "bandwidth": null,
                    "host_encryption_key_status": "none",
                    "hosts": []
                }   
         }
    }
}
```

I would like:

```
[
  "$['purefa_info']['volumes']['mydrive-0d32e3799a']",
  "$['purefa_info']['volumes']['mydrive-55c61ab79c']"
]
```

Can you help me?
Thanks

Comment: Could edit your question to show what you've tried?

Comment: Can you also add the tag to indicate the programming language or implementation/library you are using.

Comment: I try this $.purefa_info[?(@.volumes contains 'pxcloud')].['volumes'][?(@.hosts == 0)] on https://jsonpath.com, but it doesn't match.

Comment: pxcloud is not present in your JSON. are you sure you have include the complete JSON in the post? Also `contains` is not supported in  https://jsonpath.com/

Comment: If you are using java port (Jayway jsonpath) use https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/

Comment: @AkshayG, you're right but even with the good pattern my drive, same problem. I will try to do it in Ansible with json query.

Comment: @philoub you need to mention which library and programming language you are using.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using [JSONPath-Plus](https://github.com/JSONPath-Plus/JSONPath) which is used in https://jsonpath.com/ you can use the below expression.

```
$.purefa_info.*[?(@property.match(/mydrive/) && @.hosts == 0)]
```

**Note : @property is not present in the original [spec](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/index.html#e2).**